# Simulate and present normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, matlab, simulation

My task is to compare different methods of simulating normal distribution. For example, I use following code, to generate 2 vectors, each 1000 values (Box-Muller method):

```
    k=1;
    mu=0;
    N = 1000;
    alpha = rand(1, N);
    beta = rand(1, N);
    val1 = sqrt(-2 * log(alpha)) .* sin(2 * pi * beta);
    val2 = sqrt(-2 * log(alpha)) .* cos(2 * pi * beta);


    hist([val1,val2]);
    hold on;
    %Now I want to make normal distr pdf over hist to see difference
    [f,x] = ecdf(mu+sigma*[val1,val2]);
    p = normpdf(x,mu, sigma);
    plot(x,p*N,'r');
```

However, it's look very ugly - I can't distinct `val1` from `val2` and also my pdf doesn't fit histogram well. I think I'm doing something wrong with this pdf, but I don't know what. I found on the Internet different code:

```
r = rand(1000,2); % 2 cols of uniform rand
%Box-Muller
%n = sqrt(-2*log(r(:,1)))*[1,1].*[cos(2*pi*r(:,2)), sin(2*pi*r(:,2))];
hist(n) % plot two histograms
```

It looks better, but I don't know how to plot normal distribution pdf over it - method with ecdf cause error.
I'm rather new in Matlab and sometimes I make simple mistakes (like with vector dimensions) but for now I barely can see them.
Can someone help me with above or propose another way to simulate normal random variables and comparision to it (with B-M method or another, just not so complicated)?

Comment: Why would you want to distinguish `val1` from `val2`? They are just the even- and odd-numbered return values that you would get if you used this method to implement a function to generate values of a normal distribution.

Answer (score 0):

I think your plots have different scales, corrected code would look like this:

```
clear all;
sigma=1; mu=0; N = 1000;
alpha = rand(1, N); beta = rand(1, N);
val1 = sqrt(-2 * log(alpha)) .* sin(2 * pi * beta);
val2 = sqrt(-2 * log(alpha)) .* cos(2 * pi * beta);
vals = [val1,val2];

Nbins = 50; [h,hx] = hist(vals,Nbins);
bar(hx,h*0.5/(hx(2)-hx(1)))
hold on;

%Now I want to make normal distr pdf over hist to see difference
[f,x] = ecdf(mu+sigma*vals);
p = normpdf(x,mu, sigma);
plot(x,p*N,'r');
```

As mentioned in the comments, quantitative comparison of the distributions requires performing statistical tests (e.g. goodness of fit http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodness_of_fit)